# Filter JSON data with some column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below json data.
I want to filter using url and skill and yyyy_mm column and create the new data in json format.

I have 2 requirements here:-

Using AND operator:

1. filter using url column, yyyy_mm & skills column, suppose if i pass url as http://google.com and skills = C# and yyyy_mm = 2017-12
   Just like sql - where yyyy_mm = '2017-10' and skills = 'C#' and url like '%google.com%'. Then it should return me all matching data.

Using OR operator:

2. filter using url , yyyy_mm & skills column. So in this case whatever matching rows should be returned.
   Just like sql - where yyyy_mm = '2017-12' and (skills = 'C#' OR skills = 'vb.net') and url like '%google.com%'. Then it should return me all matching data.

```js
var tempData =[
  {"url":"http://google.com/shjj/player","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"C#","count":3},
  {"url":"http://google.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"C#","count":4}
  {"url":"http://google.com/jkl/uop","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"C#","count":4},               
  {"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"vb.net","count":10},
  {"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-11","skills":"vb.net","count":5},
  {"url":"https://yahoo.com/player/fast","yyyy_mm":"2017-11","skills":"vb.net","count":6},
  {"url":"google.com/lope/fgkl","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"vb.net","count":10},
  {"url":"http://google.com/gog/blab","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"vb.net","count":11},
  {"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"json","count":100}
  {"url":"yahoo.com/onj/sfd","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"C#","count":200}
]
```

Comment: Please share your code/attempt. SO is not get code for free site.

Comment: Looks like a homework for tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a filter function like this

```js
var tempData =[{"url":"http://google.com/shjj/player","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"C#","count":3},{"url":"http://google.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"C#","count":4},{"url":"http://google.com/jkl/uop","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"C#","count":4},{"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-12","skills":"vb.net","count":10},{"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-11","skills":"vb.net","count":5},{"url":"https://yahoo.com/player/fast","yyyy_mm":"2017-11","skills":"vb.net","count":6},{"url":"google.com/lope/fgkl","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"vb.net","count":10},{"url":"http://google.com/gog/blab","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"vb.net","count":11},{"url":"yahoo.com","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"json","count":100},{"url":"yahoo.com/onj/sfd","yyyy_mm":"2017-10","skills":"C#","count":200}]

function filter(filterObj, andOr) {
    if(andOr === 'and')
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce(function(arr, key) {
            return arr.filter(function(data){
                return data[key] === filterObj[key]
            })
        }, tempData)
    else
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce(function(arr, key, index) {
            return (index != 0 ? arr : []).filter(function(data) {
                return data[key] !== filterObj[key]
            }).concat(
            tempData.filter(function(data) {
                return data[key] === filterObj[key]
            }))
        }, tempData)
}

console.log("with 'or' operation", filter({count:4, yyyy_mm: "2017-10"}, "or"))
console.log("with 'and' operation", filter({count:4, yyyy_mm: "2017-10"}, "and"))
console.log("with single", filter({count:4}, "and"))
```

Comment: Will above solution return me SQL AND/OR operator data in JSON?
Like 
1). url like '%google.com%' and yyyy_mm = '2017-12' and skills = 'C#'
2). url like '%google.com%' and yyyy_mm = '2017-12' and (skills = 'C#' or skills = 'vb.net'
Please answer me. I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: Sorry it accept only `and` operation, wait i will update my code

Comment: check now, we can pass `and`, `or` as param

Comment: function filte1r(filterObj, andOr) {
            if(andOr === 'and')
                return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key) => arr.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key]), tempData)
            else
                return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key, index) => (index !=0 && arr || []).filter((data) => data[key] !== filterObj[key]).concat(tempData.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key])), tempData)
        }
=> sign is not working giving syntax error

Comment: `sign is not working giving error` can you explain more?, can you run the above snippet

Comment: I pasted below function in js file :- it's giving an Expected expression or syntex error in => Sign also filterObj[key] - too many errors . looks like not a javascript file
function filte1r(filterObj, andOr) 
{
    if (andOr === 'and')
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key) => arr.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key]), tempData)
     else
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key, index) => (index !=0 && arr || []).filter((data) => data[key] !== filterObj[key]).concat(tempData.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key])), tempData)
}

Comment: oh.. may be arrow function not working, i will change that, one sec

Comment: Please provide me the working code asap. i really help

Comment: @Rajesh had updated my code if works plz accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
 getData("www.abcd.com","C#","1999-12");
function getData(url , skill , date){
   $.each(tempData,function(index,value){

     if(value.url == url && value.skills == skill && value.yyyy_mm == date ){
       result[index] = { url:value.url , skills:value.skills , yyyy_mm:value.yyyy_mm } ; 
     }else if(value.url == url){
        result[index] = {url:value.url}
     }elseif( ....)
       ....       
   })
}
```

I have given only example for AND operation and rest I have represented with ... as You just need to add coditions there in If and rest will work ....

Comment: function filte1r(filterObj, andOr) 
{
    if (andOr === 'and')
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key) => arr.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key]), tempData)
     else
        return Object.keys(filterObj).reduce((arr, key, index) => (index !=0 && arr || []).filter((data) => data[key] !== filterObj[key]).concat(tempData.filter((data) => data[key] === filterObj[key])), tempData)
}
Above function giving me expected expression in => sign.

Comment: @Rajesh ` } else if( ....) ... `  write your code here those  . . .  means fill those blanks